# Changing XML using LXML and Python

Tags: python, lxml

I have a XML file "definitions.xml" with below content.

```
<Definitions>
  <Process name="en">
    <property name="am">OLD_A</property>
    <property name="24hours" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">OLD_B</property>
  </Process>
</Definitions>
```

I want to modify the file as below:

```
<Definitions>
  <Process name="en">
    <property name="am">NEW_A</property>
    <property name="24hours" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">NEW_B</property>
  </Process>
</Definitions>
```

I have tried below code:

```
from lxml import etree

def Definations_Parser():
 global Definations_tree
 global Definations_root
 parser =  etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text = True)
 Definations_tree = etree.parse('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\definitions.xml', parser)
 Definations_root = Definations_tree.getroot()

def Definations_File_Modify():
    Process_1 = Definations_root.find('Process')
    property_1 = Process_1.find('property[@name="am"]')
    print ('Current value is:', property_1.get('name'))

def Definations_File_Write():
 Definations_tree.write('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\definitions.xml', pretty_print = True)

Definations_Parser()
Definations_File_Modify()
Definations_File_Write()
```

How can I get current present values "OLD_A" and "OLD_B" and change it to "NEW_A" and "NEW_B" ?

Comment: I think that you need to create a new element node which needs to replace the original one. See also here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493724/python-lxml-using-iterparse-to-edit-and-output-xml

Comment: Thanks tangoal for the response however I think I have a different situation than the link you mentioned.Is it possible for you to add in the code ?

Comment: I think you just can do property_1.text = "NEW_A" to change its text content. This is indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570460/how-to-create-a-text-node-with-lxml

Answer (score 0):

Like @tangoal mentioned in the comments, you use the `text` property of the element like so:

```
from lxml import etree

def Definations_Parser():
    global Definations_tree
    global Definations_root
    parser =  etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text = True)
    Definations_tree = etree.parse('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\definitions.xml', parser)
    Definations_root = Definations_tree.getroot()

def Definations_File_Modify():
    Process_1 = Definations_root.find('Process')
    property_1 = Process_1.find('property[@name="am"]')
    print(property_1.text)
    property_1.text = 'NEW_A'
    print(property_1.text)

    property_2 = Process_1.find('property[@name="24hours"]')
    print(property_2.text)
    property_2.text = 'NEW_B'
    print(property_2.text)

def Definations_File_Write():
    Definations_tree.write('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\definitions.xml', pretty_print = True)

Definations_Parser()
Definations_File_Modify()
Definations_File_Write()
```